# System unresponsive after bootup - HDD light fully on

Tags: xubuntu, hard-drive, 19.04

I'm running a variant of Ubuntu called Xubuntu, and it has been going fine the last couple of days. But now, every time I boot, shortly after the process completes, the hard disk activity is fully on, and the system appears to be super unresponsive. Caps lock/Num lock keys do not respond. Mouse unresponsive. Can't do anything but wait. Nothing works.

Tried systemrescuecd and used the fsck utility on my hard-drive. Nothing.

Tried to use the recovery console and used the clean, dpkg and grub commands. Nothing.

If anyone can help me fix this, it would be a good help. I have a terminal window open when it boots up before the system goes full crazy with the hard drive, so that could be a help.

Comment: Possible causes:  thrashing, ie. your system reaches a out-of-memory condition and it has to temporarily write memory to disk to create some free memory, thus disk light will be on & system becomes super-slow as it's 'thrashing'.  You didn't tell us how much RAM you have, what you're doing so i have no idea if this occurs (unlikely on a just-booted system, and I tested Xubuntu on machines with 1gb of ram).  Second thought is you have tons of pictures, and the system is indexing them (ie. creating thumbnail pictures for your file manager `thunar`).  Do you have loads of pictures on your disk?

Comment: Sorry about the delay, but mine is 2GB of RAM. It also now boots into a black screen with a weird "X" cursor that normally occurs when you use xkill. So now I have two problems in one. Is there any way to fix this problem? The only way out is power-cycling, either by physically pulling the plug, or holding the power button until the computer turns off and turning it back on again –

Comment: So, my plan is to fix the thrashing problem, and then the black screen with weird cursor on bootup. Is there any way to do this through a recovery console? Because it doesn't happen on the console. I don't have anything important on this PC, but it's still really irritating.

Comment: Power cycling should not be your only way out - have you tried 'magic' sysrq keys; they are recognized by the linux kernel & obeyed and allow a safe shutdown that protects data. You don't describe a frozen system, so they should work. If you don't remember the keys; use another device to quickly search & refresh yourself (wikipedia etc; and why I used the magic in my first reference). If power-down is your only option - you have other problems beyond thrashing.  Halting power creates other filesystem problems because of unclean shutdowns that need fixing first before you can re-use system.

Comment: Sorry about the long delay... I know that It's nearly been a month (Been very busy lately). So, I checked, and my computer is configured with magic SysRq turned on. Which sequence of magic SysRq codes should I use to fix my black screen with weird cursor problem (and the excess HDD usage)?